# How to avoid java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException when using java.nio.file.Files.move()?

Tags: java, exception, java.nio.file

My Java program (see below) sometimes crashes with a java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException in a java.nio.File.move() method execution.

I could not understand why this exception is thrown and I have no bypass for now.

Here is an example of the exception :

```
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\PROJECTS\PROJECT0\CHANGES -> C:\PROJECTS\PROJECT0\GEN70\CHANGES
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:95)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:109)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileCopy.move(WindowsFileCopy.java:399)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.move(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:299)
    at java.nio.file.Files.move(Files.java:1406)
    at com.ibm.cldt.engine.tool.TestMove.generate(TestMove.java:75)
    at com.ibm.cldt.engine.tool.TestMove.createAndUseProject(TestMove.java:42)
    at com.ibm.cldt.engine.tool.TestMove.main(TestMove.java:25)
```

Here the problem is detected on "GEN70" of "PROJECT0", but, it varies. For example, here is another run :
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\PROJECTS\PROJECT2\CHANGES -> C:\PROJECTS\PROJECT2\GEN33\CHANGES

Note : before running the program, you have to delete the directory C:/PROJECTS if you have one.

What can I do to prevent my program from throwing this exception ?

I run this code on Windows 10 Enterprise, and an IBM JRE 1.8.

```
java version "1.8.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build pwa6480sr4fp5-20170421_01(SR4 FP5))
IBM J9 VM (build 2.8, JRE 1.8.0 Windows 10 amd64-64 Compressed References 20170419_344392 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - R28_20170419_1004_B344392
JIT  - tr.r14.java_20170419_344392
GC   - R28_20170419_1004_B344392_CMPRSS
J9CL - 20170419_344392)
JCL - 20170420_01 based on Oracle jdk8u131-b11
```

Here is the code. You can run it as Java standalone application. Before launching, check that you do not have a C:/PROJECTS directory.

I will be surprised if the program execution ends without exception on your machine. If that is the case, please retry ...

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;

public class TestMove
{
    private static final String PROJECTS_ROOT = "C:/PROJECTS";
    private static final int NUMBER_OF_PROJECTS = 10;
    private static final int NUMBER_OF_GENERATIONS = 100;
    private static final int NUMBER_OF_CHANGES = 10;


    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        try
        {
            for ( int project = 0; project < NUMBER_OF_PROJECTS; ++project )
            {
                createAndUseProject( "PROJECT"+project );
            }
        }
        catch ( IOException ioe )
        {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private static void createAndUseProject( String projectName ) throws IOException
    {
        Path projectRoot = Paths.get( PROJECTS_ROOT, projectName );
        Files.createDirectories( projectRoot );
        for ( int generation = 0; generation < NUMBER_OF_GENERATIONS; ++generation )
        {
            addNewChanges( projectRoot );
            generate( projectRoot, generation );
        }
    }


    private static final StandardOpenOption[] CREATE_APPEND =
        new StandardOpenOption[] { StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.APPEND };


    private static void addNewChanges( Path projectRoot ) throws IOException
    {
        Path changesDir = projectRoot.resolve( "CHANGES" );
        Files.createDirectory( changesDir );
        String newLine = System.lineSeparator();
        Path changesLogFile = changesDir.resolve( "changes.log" );
        try ( BufferedWriter changesWriter = Files.newBufferedWriter( changesLogFile, CREATE_APPEND ) )
        {
            for ( int change = 0; change < NUMBER_OF_CHANGES; ++change )
            {
                changesWriter.append( "This is my change number "+ change ).append( newLine );
            }
        }
    }


    private static void generate( Path projectRoot, int generation ) throws IOException
    {
        Path generationDir = projectRoot.resolve( "GEN"+generation );
        Files.createDirectory( generationDir );
        Path projectChangesDir = projectRoot.resolve( "CHANGES" );
        Path generationChangesDir = generationDir.resolve( "CHANGES" );

        // Here is the problem : AccessDeniedException is thrown ... sometimes.
        Files.move( projectChangesDir, generationChangesDir );

        Path changesLogFile = generationChangesDir.resolve( "changes.log" );
        try ( BufferedReader changesReader = Files.newBufferedReader( changesLogFile ) )
        {
            for ( String change = changesReader.readLine(); change != null; change = changesReader.readLine() )
                computeChange( change );
        }
    }


    private static void computeChange( String change )
    {
        // Do whatever needed ...
    }
}
```

What can I do to prevent my program from throwing this exception ?

COMPLEMENTS
From the first answers, I downloaded the Oracle JDK 1.8.0_221 from Oracle website. Then, I used javac and java commands to compile and run my program from a CMD window.
Here is the transcript:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.356]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\tmp\Java>dir
 Volume in drive C is Windows
 Volume Serial Number is 8A56-3036

 Directory of C:\tmp\Java

09/24/2019  06:57 PM    <DIR>          .
09/24/2019  06:57 PM    <DIR>          ..
09/24/2019  06:54 PM             2,678 TestMove.java
               1 File(s)          2,678 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  353,415,393,280 bytes free

C:\tmp\Java>"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\bin\javac" TestMove.java

C:\tmp\Java>"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\bin\java" TestMove
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\PROJECTS\PROJECT0\CHANGES -> C:\PROJECTS\PROJECT0\GEN97\CHANGES
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:83)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileCopy.move(WindowsFileCopy.java:387)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.move(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:287)
        at java.nio.file.Files.move(Files.java:1395)
        at TestMove.generate(TestMove.java:73)
        at TestMove.createAndUseProject(TestMove.java:40)
        at TestMove.main(TestMove.java:23)

C:\tmp\Java>
```

Same problem with a standard up-to-date JVM, an no eclipse. I feel bad ;-) ...

UPDATE :
I have found this bypass. It works well, but I do not feel good with it in my app in production.
I have replaced those two lines :

```
// Here is the problem : AccessDeniedException is thrown ... sometimes.
Files.move( projectChangesDir, generationChangesDir );
```

With this code:

```
while ( true )
{
    try
    {
        Files.move( projectChangesDir, generationChangesDir );
        break;
    }
    catch ( IOException ioe ) { ++failures; }
}
```

It works suprisingly well and makes it possible for my program to run until its normal end. But ... well ... not so satisfactory. At the end failures counter is around 10, sometimes less, sometimes more, for a total of 1000 attempts (10 projects x 100 generations).

Comment: I've run your code three times in a row without a single problem, I'm going to guess you've got an explorer or cmd open on the problematic path

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your answer. I have no explorer window at all. By the way, the C:/PROJECTS doesnt exist before I launch the program.

Comment: To be sure, I have just shut down my machine. Restarted. Launched Eclipse with a shortcut. Run TestProject program, and : java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\PROJECTS\PROJECT0\CHANGES -> C:\PROJECTS\PROJECT0\GEN39\CHANGES. I wonder what specifically make a problem on GEN39 and not on GEN38 ?

Comment: That's annoying, that was the easy fix. I don't see anything wrong with your code, maybe a bug of the IBM JVM? I've tested with the Oracle one. You might want to check a file locks explorer, there are a few such tools for windows, it might show locks where there shouldn't be. About the varying failure directory, I guess it's a race condition of some sort which has little chance of happening but high enough that it will consistently reproduce when you do it 100 times in a row

Comment: That said it seems to me you could simplify your code so that it directly generates the desired data in the generationChangesDir rather than first generate it in the projectChangesDir then move that to the generationChangesDir, that would avoid the problem altogether.

Comment: This code is not the real code of my app. This sample code has been designed only to make this post on StackOverflow. In the real code, the generations are performed in parrallel in separate threads.

Comment: I see your JRE isn't up-to-date, I'd try updating it

Comment: I downloaded and make the test with Oracle JDK 1.8.8_221. Same problem. Compiled with "javac" and ran with "java" commands.

Comment: Sorry, I meant Oracle JDK 1.8.0_221

Comment: I tested on a second computer (in particular to test on an HDD rather than an SDD as in my first test) and have yet again been able to run 3 times in a row without any error. I think you really ought to check OS-level logs of the file creation/lock release/file move to see what's wrong. [This superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/402792/can-i-log-file-operations-create-modify-delete-in-windows) might be a good start

Comment: I will try to ask a system programmer, which I am not, to investigate this. By the way, my C drive is actually a SSD. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: is any other program on your computer (or possibly you using file explorer) interacting with the generated directories while the program is running?

Comment: I don't think so. I just created this example with root directory "C:/PROJECTS" and "GENxx" subdirectories for this post on StackOverflow. I also tried with various names and locations (for example in my home directory) and that is the same.

Comment: i think the timer is fine. your intereacting with a OS that has async tasks. Your creating and renaming folders too fast. I have mny times added 100 milli second timers in Java applets, batch programs, IOT projects! Just add the sleep and move on. Happens less on ubuntu :-)

Comment: is it possible there is a virus scanner or some other security type program running which automatically scans new files/folders?

Comment: I just noticed that you are doing this in a multi-threaded manner.  is it possible your threads are conflicting with each other?  i.e. does it work if you use a single thread?

Comment: There is no multithreading in this program. See the code, it is pure sequential.

Comment: I have added the (nonexistent) directory "C:/PROJECT" in the exclusion list of the Windows Security/Virus & threat protection/Virus & threat protection settings/Manage settings/Exclusions, but nothing has changed. Same results.

Comment: Can u create a folder called c:/p/ add it to exclusion list of windows security and any other anti virus program you have? Then run code so it creates c:/p/projects folder and other files below it? Might help to exclude existing folder and use that as root folder

Comment: I see : your advice is to add a permanent top directory "c:/p", put it in the exclusion list of my antivirus, and modify my program to create all my stuff in subdirectories of p. Good advice, I will try it in a few minutes ...

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem remains after this operation.

Comment: Does this behavior still happen on other people's computers?  can you temporarily disable things like virus scanner, etc?

Comment: You said the program isn't multi-threaded in response to one of my questions, yet earlier you commented "In the real code, the generations are performed in parrallel in separate threads."?

Comment: The "real code" is an application on which I work. It has nothing to see with the small sample I have shared in this question, which exhibits a crash. I need help on this small sample, which has no multithreading at all, as anybody reading the question can see.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is rather old, and I don't have a clear answer, but a suspicion.

I'm having they same problem sometimes, but only when trying to move executable files (or folders containing such), and it happens more often when my computer is busy doing other stuff.
My suspicion is that an (corporate level) antivirus software is the culprit. Sometimes it isn't fast enough to scan the file and still has a lock on it when your program tries to move it.

I also didn't find a nice solution, and use a practically identical workaround to the one you are using. Disabling the antivirus isn't an option here, because even if I get an exception from my company, we also have to ensure the software works for our costumers without the need disable antivirus.

Answer (score 0):

`AccessDeniedException` suggests there is a permissions problem. How are you executing your program, and does the user have permissions to create the c:/projects directory, and write to it?

One option would be to try running your code as an admin user. This post should help with that: https://superuser.com/questions/42537/is-there-any-sudo-command-for-windows

Comment: see the coments, he is creating the folder. everything works sometimes. and when he add a sleep issue goes away - works every time

Comment: "By the way, the C:/PROJECTS doesnt exist before I launch the program. – Hervé Le Bars 3 hours ago"

Comment: Creation of the C:/PROJECTS directory always run fine. Same for creation of GENxx and CHANGES subdirectories, and for creating and writing the "changes.log" files. The problem occurs when moving the PROJECT/CHANGES subdirectory to GENxx/CHANGES, and just one time for any ~100 attempts (my program repeats the equivalent move 1000 times, ~10 will fail).

Answer (score 0):

For now, as far as I know, only Aaron (https://stackoverflow.com/users/1678362/aaron) did try the sample Java code I provided in my question (thank you Aaron). He did not reproduce the issue.

I wonder what could be the difference between our two setups. Maybe the fact that my Windows 10 is a Professional one ?

Also, I would be happy if others can try the small code sample on their machine ... especially with various setups, including Windows 10 Professional.